# Any extension for customize the dashboard

Tags: extension

I want a extension that can change the dashboard layout and configure as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pete's answer, you can also put Views blocks into CiviCRM dashlets: https://civicrm.org/blog/brandonferrell/drupal-views-in-civicrm-dashlets

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is nu such extension at the moment. You are quite welcome to either develop one or offer funding to have an expert develop one?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Drupal you can build Views blocks and set them at the dashboard path but 'above' the civi dashboard and hence set up whatever you like there

Comment: Do you have a sample code ?

Comment: sample code of a view? not sure i follow. use Views and Views UI to create a query for the type of civi entity you need, set is as a Block display, then set the block to show in a region on your theme that is in use for civicrm and specify the required page.